# The type of the right operand ('ConfirmAction') isn't a subtype or a > supertype of the left operand ('Future<ConfirmAction?>')

Tags: flutter, dart

How to fix

> The type of the right operand ('ConfirmAction') isn't a subtype or a
> supertype of the left operand ('Future<ConfirmAction?>').

this does not cause runtime errors, but it does show the recommendation in the IDE

```
return Dismissible(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
      onDismissed: (direction) async {
        await _asyncConfirmDialog(context).then((value) {    
          if (value == ConfirmAction.cancel) { //here
            ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happens inside `_asyncConfirmDialog`, but it looks like the returned value is of type `Future<Future<ConfirmAction?>>`, which makes `value` has the type of `Future<ConfirmAction?>`. You need to put the `await` keyword to make it a `ConfirmAction?` (which is comparable to `ConfirmAction`)

```
await _asyncConfirmDialog(context).then((value) async { // (1) put async here    
  if (await value == ConfirmAction.cancel) { // (2) put await here
```